# Chart CalloutAnnotation with MultiColor Text

Tags: vb.net, mschart

I have a callout annotation on my chart that displays text variable name "StringContent" in Red Color Using ForeColor Property.
But I want a custom text colors i.e. some text will be blue and and some in red color. I have searched through the MSDN and there isn't any OnPaint method to override to make a custom callout. Please guide me. Thank you.
The code snippet is shown below:

```
Chart1.Annotations.Clear()
            ta = New CalloutAnnotation
            With ta
                .AnchorDataPoint = Chart1.Series(0).Points(result.PointIndex)
                .Text = ":::    {  - - DETAILS  - - }    ::: " & StrDup(2, vbLf) & StringContent
                .ForeColor = Color.Red 

                .Text += "Blue Colored Text Will Go here"
                .ForeColor = Color.Blue  '// With this line all text obviously will go blue

                .ShadowColor = Color.Black
                .ShadowOffset = 2

                .Font = New Font("Franklin Gothic Book", 9.5, FontStyle.Regular)
                .SmartLabelStyle.MovingDirection = LabelAlignmentStyles.Center
                .SmartLabelStyle.AllowOutsidePlotArea = LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.No
                .AllowMoving = True
            End With
```

Comment: You are right.There is no paint event for the elements inside a chart. You could try to either 1) ownerdraw instead of the annotation or use two or 2) more annotations, each with a text color of its own. you can group them for easier handling in an annotationgroup. Or 3) you can create a multicolored image and show that in an annotation.

Comment: I have found a way to implement custom tooltip control instead of Callout Annotation.